# Aggregate ENTIRE rows based on single field without querying source twice or using CTEs?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, teradata, greatest-n-per-group

Assume I have the following table:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 | field3 |
+--------+--------+--------+
| a      | a      |      1 |
| a      | b      |      2 |
| a      | c      |      3 |
| b      | a      |      1 |
| b      | b      |      2 |
| c      | b      |      2 |
| c      | b      |      3 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to select only the rows where `field3` is the minimum value, so only these rows:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 | field3 |
+--------+--------+--------+
| a      | a      |      1 |
| b      | a      |      1 |
| c      | b      |      2 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

The most popular solution is to query the source twice, once directly and then joined to a subquery where the source is queried again and then aggregated.  However, since my data source is actually a derived table/subquery itself, I'd have to duplicate the subquery in my SQL which is ugly.  The other option is to use the WITH CTE and reuse the subquery which would be nice, but **Teradata, the database I am using**, doesn't support CTEs in views, though it does in macros which is not an option for me now.

So is it possible in standard SQL to group multiple records into a single record by using only a single field in the aggregation *without* querying the source twice or using a CTE?

Comment: Minimum regarding to field1?

Comment: @jarlh Yes.  The results in my second table show what I'd expect to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using a window function:

```
select *
from (
  select column_1, column_2, column_3, 
         min(column_3) over (partition by column_1) as min_col_3
  from the_table
) t
where column_3 = min_col_3;
```

The above is standard SQL and I believe Teradata also supports window functions.

The derived table is necessary because you can't refer to a column alias in the `where` clause - at least not in standard SQL.
I *think* [Teradata actually allows that](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_111A/ch01.032.234.html) using the `qualify` operator, but as I have never used it, I am not sure:

```
select *
from the_table
qualify min(column_3) over (partition by column_1) = column_3;
```

Comment: I think that is `min(column_3) over (partition by column_1)` in the `qualify` clause.

Comment: I cannot believe I did not think of this and now I recall that I've already been doing this elsewhere.  Thanks for the knock to the head that I needed!  I haven't wrapped my head around window functions, so I've been using template SQL such as `rank() over (partition by anchorfield order by incrementfield)`.  It works, but I still need to learn up on window functions (didn't even know that's what they were called).

Comment: Instead of MIN you might also use RANK, depending on the actual data one or the other might be more efficient: `qualify rank() over (partition by column_1 order by column_3) = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if there are no other row with same field1 value but a lower field3 value:

```
select * from table t1
where not exists (select 1 from table t2
                  where t2.field1 = t1.field1
                    and t2.field3 < t1.field3)
```

Comment: I'd imagine that this is also a sub-query that OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @TabAlleman Exactly.  I do not want to reference the source twice in the same master query which is exactly what this SQL is doing.